Stargate "instructional" videos
There is a series of short Stargate "instructional" videos posted to Youtube here: 


The Youtube was posted in 2009, a couple of years after the SG1 series finale first aired. The videos are hosted by Michael Shanks in-character as Daniel Jackson, covering  various topics relating to the Stargate, the Stargate program, extra-terrestrial races, etc. from an in-universe perspective. Given the references, they must have been created after the season 9/10 Ori arc was established.
I don't believe it to be a "deep fake" because I don't believe the technology was sufficiently developed at the time of posting, so that would seem to be the real Michael Shanks reprising his role as Daniel Jackson, presumably authorized by the studio. I don't recall seeing any of this material used anywhere in the franchise (series or movies), so I am wondering what motivated its production. Was it meant to be used for cutaways? Was it intended to be promotional material perhaps for syndication?

Why do they have a linguist explaining hyperspace? Wouldn't it have made more sense to throw in Carter or somebody else who actually knows the math? (Yes, I know, out-of-universe he's the actor they had available.)

@Kevin Like Carter, Jackson seems to be something of a polymath (out-of-universe, seems writers had to imbue one or the other with all sorts of skills peripheral to their nominal specialties for the sake of a given script). He's not just a linguist but also an archaeologist, he knows some biology/paleontology, and is something of a quick study on alien tech. That qualifies him as a science communicator, which works for the videos. Besides, he can be quite affable. While it might seem to make more sense to have Carter explain hyperspace, she tends to get overly technical.

In order to connect the SG1 series with the Stargate: Universe show, actor Michael Shanks agreed to make a brief cameo appearance in the first episode, providing a series of instructional videos to the new 'everyman' character, Eli Wallace. We see these being fast-forwarded through and catch small glimpses of them in SGU: Air, Part I.

Shanks also confirmed that fans looking for Daniel Jackson to have an expansive role in the pilot for Universe are going to be disappointed.
“It’s a cameo. It’s a popping in, popping out kind of thing,” he said. “They’ve got a lot of cast that they definitely need to facilitate. Certainly the Stargate audience knows my character and Richard’s character and Amanda’s character and the others that show up very well. So they have to spend some time developing their world and fleshing out their characters. So I’m just a face.”
Shanks talks Universe, new TV movie

These minisodes were subsequently released on the MGM website in order to publicise and promote the series, as well as appearing on the DVD box set extras for SGU season 1, where they received an official title as the "Stargate 101" videos
